# Не понимаю в чем ошибка

Tags: python, python-3.x

Решил написать более сложный калькулятор, на этапе тестирования появилась ошибка, но я не понимаю в чем конкретно проблема, вроде все правильно написал:

```
mathExample = input('Введи пример: ')  # пока нужно вводить выражение через пробел

mathExampleList = mathExample.split()  # создание списка из элементов примера
countFirstPriorityOperations = 0  # кол-во действий 1 приоритета(/,*)
countSecondPriorityOperations = 0  # кол-во действий 2 приоритета(+, -)

for i in mathExampleList:  # цикл считает кол-во действий
  if (i == '+') or (i == '-'):
    countSecondPriorityOperations += 1
  elif (i == '*') or (i == '/'):
    countFirstPriorityOperations += 1

if countFirstPriorityOperations > 0:  # если есть умножение или деление
  for i in mathExampleList:
    if (i == '*') or (i == '/'):
      if i == '*':
        mathExampleList[mathExampleList.index('*') - 1:mathExampleList.index('*') + 2] = \
          float(mathExampleList[mathExampleList.index('*') - 1]) * \
          float(mathExampleList[mathExampleList.index('*') + 1])  # замена выражения его результатом
      elif i == '/':
        mathExampleList[mathExampleList.index('/') - 1:mathExampleList.index('/') + 2] = \
          float(mathExampleList[mathExampleList.index('/') - 1]) / \
          float(mathExampleList[mathExampleList.index('/') + 1])  # замена выражения его результатом

if countSecondPriorityOperations > 0:
  for i in mathExampleList:
    if (i == '+') or (i == '-'):
      if i == '+':
        mathExampleList[mathExampleList.index('+') - 1:mathExampleList.index('+') + 2] = \
          float(mathExampleList[mathExampleList.index('+') - 1]) + \
          float(mathExampleList[mathExampleList.index('+') + 1])  # замена выражения его результатом
      elif i == '-':
        mathExampleList[mathExampleList.index('-') - 1:mathExampleList.index('-') + 2] = \
          float(mathExampleList[mathExampleList.index('-') - 1]) - \
          float(mathExampleList[mathExampleList.index('-') + 1])  # замена выражения его результатом

print(*mathExampleList)
```

ошибка возникает в строке типа:

```
mathExampleList[mathExampleList.index('*') - 1:mathExampleList.index('*') + 2] = \
```

Пример:
Ввод: `2 + 2`
Вывод:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\programming\python\scripts\new\calculator.py", line 29, in <module>
    mathExampleList[mathExampleList.index('+') - 1:mathExampleList.index('+') + 2] = \\
TypeError: can only assign an iterable.
```

Я долго пытался понять, в чем ошибка, но точно так  и не понял, возможно из-за того, что я выполнял арифметические операции, когда делал срез, либо из-за того, что использовал метод в срезе, я так и не понял

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19877524/typeerror-can-only-assign-an-iterable-values-to-list
По-моему здесь ответ на твой вопрос, я только что проверил и сделал вот так

```
mathExampleList[mathExampleList.index('+') - 1:mathExampleList.index('+') + 2] = [\
                    float(mathExampleList[mathExampleList.index('+') - 1]) + \
                    float(mathExampleList[mathExampleList.index('+') + 1])]
```

Comment: Спасибо, вроде все нормально работает теперь, но только я не понял как? И зачем ты добавил квадратные скобки?

Comment: Как я понял, в промежуток в массиве можно вставлять тоже только промежуток, могу ошибаться